# footprint soap api + maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, soap-client, footprint

I'm working on the footprint soap api and somehow there is quite the same complexType definition on the wsdl xsd schema. see in this [link](https://gist.github.com/frederickney/2916285e84b95d86a5e8d9325bdff082) with **GetItemId** and **getItemId** for example:

The question is it is possible to configure the **maven-jaxb2-plugin** to generate the java classes by keeping the case sensitivity? so the result would be two class files named **GetItemId.java** and **getItemId.java**

Comment: A class should usually start with uppercase character furthermore if you change one class you have to change all other related classes as well. Apart from that: What is the problem with the classname?

Comment: the main issue is that GetItemId refers to a data content object and getItemId is the triggered function to call on the soap service

Comment: link to [wsdl](https://gist.github.com/frederickney/6618d71d2b2b16756d32d002bca4ba2b)